# Is better to define a variable for CoroutineScope and resuse it or is it better to call CoroutineScope repeatedly?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

What is the best practice for using `CoroutineScope` (MainScope in Android)? Below is an example that defines the scope as a variable that can be reused, this allows me to all the jobs running in the scope when I exit the activity.

```
val mainScope = MainScope()


// do something scope

mainScope.launch { ... }

mainScope.launch { ... }

mainScope.launch { ... }

mainScope.cancel()
```

Or this approach, where I just call `MainScope` and then do the work I want in that scope.

```
MainScope().launch { ... }

MainScope().launch { ... }

MainScope().launch { ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your examples are not that much different. When you reuse one scope you have the ability to cancel all of them (when they are cooperative).

When you create new Scopes you need to keep all `Job`'s to cancel them. And as long your Scopes have the exact same configuration (as they do in your example) I do not see a benefit of creating new scopes every time.

**LifecycleScope**

Consider using [lifecycleScope](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/lifecycle/package-summary#lifecyclescope) when you are in an Activity or Fragment (basically any LifecycleOwner).

> This scope will be cancelled when the Lifecycle is destroyed.

Comment: And use built-in property `viewModelScope` in ViewModel class.